# Examples of smooth manifolds admitting inbetween one and a continuum of complex structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology

For smooth manifolds it is known that they can admit a unique, finitely many, or a continuum of distinct smooth structures (I don't know whether there are any examples admitting precisely a countably infinite number).

For complex manifolds there are examples of smooth manifolds admitting a unique complex structure ($\mathbb{CP}^1$) or a continuum (compact Riemann surfaces, K3 surfaces, etc.)

> **Q.** Are there examples admitting only finitely many or a countably infinite number?

By deformation theory the tangent space to the moduli space of complex structures on $X$ should be given by $H^1(X, TX)$ (at least morally) so it must be necessary for this to vanish for every possible complex structure on $X$ to have any hope.

Comment: if you allow non-closed manifolds, smooth unit disc admits exactly two complex structures I believe (one its own, the other coming from the diffeomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^2$)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Examples of smooth manifolds admitting finitely many complex structures are provided by some holomorphically rigid complex varieties.

For instance, considering [fake projective planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane) (i.e., smooth compact complex surfaces which are not the complex projective plane but have the same Betti numbers as the
complex projective plane), there are $100$ examples determined up to biholomorphism, but only $50$ examples determined up to isometry.

In fact, the real $4$-manifold underlying any fake projective plane admits precisely *two* inequivalent complex structures, that are exchanged by complex conjugation.

Moreover, by standard results on rigidity, any minimal Kähler surface with the same fundamental group as a fake projective plane is actually biholomorphic or conjugate biholomorphic to it.

Answer (score 17):

There are countably many complex structures on $S^2 \times S^2$ up to isomorphism. Specifically, the even Hirzebruch surfaces $F_{2k}$ are the only options. This is the main result of

*Qin, Zhenbo*, [**Complex structures on certain differentiable 4-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(93)90006-H), Topology 32, No. 3, 551-566 (1993). [ZBL0796.57010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0796.57010).

The author also proves that the odd Hirzebruch surfaces are the only complex structures on the $4$-fold $\mathbb{CP}^2 \# \overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$.